# Comments à la "click to appear" with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, comments

I have a WordPress blog and I'm trying to make that when a user clicks on "Show comments" the comments section appears with a simple animation.. I used

```
 <a href="#comments" id="showcomments">Show comments</a>
```

and then:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function(){
jQuery("#showcomments").click(function () {
    jQuery("#comments").slideToggle("slow");
});
});
</script>

<div id="comments" style="display:none">
    ......
    </div>
```

This is what I achieved (scroll down to "Commenta l'articolo!"):
http://multiformeingegno.it/riflessioni/topserver-server-virtuali-made-italy/

As you can see if I click the link the comments section appears but the browser doesn't go down to the start of the section, you have to manually scroll down.. can you help me? Thanks!! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above DIV id "comments", put the following code:

```
<a name="comments">
```

You need to point where you want the user to go after the click.

Good luck! :)

Comment: Ehm.. actually I have a problem! :(
If you visit the link on my first post (with your solution applied) you can see it doesn't scroll till you can see the comments, but just at the top, where I put the <a name="comments"></a>.. I'd like to have it to scroll down to where the first comment is (visible).

I tried to move the <a name="comments"> down but it doesn't work.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: The use just <a name="comments"> :)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand.. what's different with <a name="comments"> compared to the solution you wrote in the first reply..? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Jquery as well.

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

Or you could use an anchor '#'

Answer (score 0):

Use document ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showcomments").click(function () {
      $("#comments").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the block with yours also. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the target anchor in the comment box

```
<a name="comment" ></a>
```

This is what your link is looking for to focus on