# Folding comments with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, comments

Here I already asked how to have comments to show up in my WP install when a user clicks a "Show comments" link and having the browser to automatically scroll down to the position of the comments..:
[Comments à la "click to appear" with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162124/comments-a-la-click-to-appear-with-jquery)

To understand what I'm talking about visit this link:
http://multiformeingegno.it/riflessioni/topserver-server-virtuali-made-italy/

At the end of the post there's a link that make comments appear, the problem is that the browser doesn't scroll down to the comments "position". I tried the solution posted to my previous StrackOverflow question but unfortunately it doesn't work (you can see it applied to the link posted above)..

Can you help me? Thanks in advance guys! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the browser isn't scrolling down to the comments position is because you're trying to scroll there before it's completely visible yet. One thing you could try doing is animating the document to scroll down the height of the window at the same time you're showing the comments section, like so:

```
jQuery('#showcomments').click(function(e) {
    jQuery('#comments').slideToggle('slow');
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: '+=' + jQuery(window).height() + 'px'
    }, 'slow');
});
```

You also want to change `#showcomments`, since you're no longer using it as an anchor link. I would just make it a span:

```
<span id="showcomments">Show comments</span>
```

Hope this helps!